# Редирект NextJs

Tags: nextjs, next

Ранее в NextJs v12.0.8 был реализован функционал возврата на предыдущую страницу после перехода с нее на страницу авторизации/регистрации для логина. Как в данном случае сделать рефакторинг этого кода на NextJs v14.1 ?

```html
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

import { useAuth } from '@/hooks/useAuth'

export const useAuthRedirect = () => {
    const { user } = useAuth()

    const { query, push } = useRouter()

    const redirect = query.redirect ? String(query.redirect) : '/'

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user) push(redirect)
    }, [user, redirect, push])
}
```